# Unzip file issue in Pentaho-spoon

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pdi, spoon

I'm trying to unzip a file in a job, everything's ok until the filename inside the zip has some special characters like "á, é, í, ó, ú". When the filename inside the zip has those characters I got an error and this log:

```
Unzip file - ERROR (version 8.1.0.0-365, build 8.1.0.0-365 from 2018-04-30 09.42.24 by buildguy) : Could not unzip file [file:///C:/pentaho/data/example.zip]. Exception : [MALFORMED]
Unzip file - ERROR (version 8.1.0.0-365, build 8.1.0.0-365 from 2018-04-30 09.42.24 by buildguy) : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MALFORMED
Unzip file -    at java.util.zip.ZipCoder.toString(Unknown Source)
Unzip file -    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.getZipEntry(Unknown Source)
Unzip file -    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$900(Unknown Source)
Unzip file -    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipEntryIterator.next(Unknown Source)
Unzip file -    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipEntryIterator.nextElement(Unknown Source)
Unzip file -    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipEntryIterator.nextElement(Unknown Source)
Unzip file -    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.zip.ZipFileSystem.init(ZipFileSystem.java:83)
Unzip file -    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractVfsContainer.addComponent(AbstractVfsContainer.java:49)
Unzip file -    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractFileProvider.addFileSystem(AbstractFileProvider.java:96)
Unzip file -    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractLayeredFileProvider.createFileSystem(AbstractLayeredFileProvider.java:80)
Unzip file -    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractLayeredFileProvider.findFile(AbstractLayeredFileProvider.java:56)
Unzip file -    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.impl.DefaultFileSystemManager.resolveFile(DefaultFileSystemManager.java:711)
Unzip file -    at org.pentaho.di.core.vfs.ConcurrentFileSystemManager.resolveFile(ConcurrentFileSystemManager.java:91)
Unzip file -    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.impl.DefaultFileSystemManager.resolveFile(DefaultFileSystemManager.java:648)
Unzip file -    at org.pentaho.di.core.vfs.KettleVFS.getFileObject(KettleVFS.java:152)
Unzip file -    at org.pentaho.di.core.vfs.KettleVFS.getFileObject(KettleVFS.java:109)
Unzip file -    at org.pentaho.di.job.entries.unzip.JobEntryUnZip.unzipFile(JobEntryUnZip.java:626)
Unzip file -    at org.pentaho.di.job.entries.unzip.JobEntryUnZip.processOneFile(JobEntryUnZip.java:525)
Unzip file -    at org.pentaho.di.job.entries.unzip.JobEntryUnZip.execute(JobEntryUnZip.java:470)
Unzip file -    at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:676)
Unzip file -    at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:817)
Unzip file -    at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:493)
Unzip file -    at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.run(Job.java:380)
```

How may I fix this issue?

I'm attaching image of the job: 
[Unzip File Job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sczC8.png)

Pd. I already look here and other forums.
Thanks

Comment: What is the OS you are using, the filesystem you are writing to and if known the OS and filesystem the zip file was created on?

Comment: I'm using Windows 10, and it should be NTFS. Let me check for the other information. When the filenames does not have those characters it works fine. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34857663/how-can-unzip-file-in-kettle-where-zip-content-cyrillic/35290069#35290069 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, could help someone so I'm posting it.

1. Step: Get Variables, to get the parameters I needed.
2. Step: User Defined Java Class, in here I unzip the file, changing the encoding, this is the code:

---

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveEntry;
import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;


public boolean processRow(StepMetaInterface smi, StepDataInterface sdi) throws KettleException
{

    Object[] r = getRow();
    if (r == null) {
        setOutputDone();
        return false;
    }
    Object[] outputRow = createOutputRow(r, data.outputRowMeta.size());


    String fname = getVariable("VARIABLE_NAME", null);
    String outDir = getVariable("VARIABLE_NAME", null);


    System.out.println(fname + "  " + outDir);

    try {
            java.io.File inputFile = new java.io.File(fname);
            ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(inputFile, "cp866", false);
            Enumeration enumEntry = zipFile.getEntries();
            int i = 0;
            while(enumEntry.hasMoreElements()){
                ZipArchiveEntry entry = (ZipArchiveEntry) enumEntry.nextElement();
                String entryName = entry.getName();
                System.out.println(entryName);
                OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File(outDir, entryName));
                InputStream is = zipFile.getInputStream(entry);
                IOUtils.copy(is, os);


                is.close();
                os.close();
                //Printing output fields
                get(Fields.Out, "FNAME").setValue(outputRow, fname);
                get(Fields.Out, "FileNameUnzipped").setValue(outputRow, entryName);
                putRow(data.outputRowMeta, outputRow);
            }
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            System.out.println("Faild to unzip");
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }


    return true;    
}
```

3. Step: Set Variables.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused due an incorrect encoding setting. Try starting the Spoon with this setting -Dfile.encoding=utf8
add it to your Spoon.sh or Spoon.bat